# Automatically tagging files that were last opened more than x days ago

Tags: automator, finder-tag

I want to set up a process to run each day and identify files that were last opened x days ago, then apply a tag like "to review" to those files. Those files would appear tagged in Finder with the appropriate color / tag and that tag would be searchable.

Is Automator the best bet and, if so, does anyone have a script that does something like this that I can refer to?

Comment: Automator could be the easiest depending on exactly what you are doing.  Just use the **Find Finder Items** action with your criteria.  The Label action isn't updated to use tags, but there is an action to add Finder comments.

Comment: [Automator - Deleting files with date modified older than 30 days, except if in a folder labeled red](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316282) this is close.

Comment: @ankii, The **AppleScript** solution in the link of your comment is not applicable here, with basic vanilla **AppleScript**  anyway, as the **AppleScript** dictionary for **Finder** does not have a `date last opened` _property_, nor can it apply a _custom_ **tag** with the _files_ `label index` _property_. Using `mdfind`, `xargs` and `xattr` in a _shell script_ IMO is a better way to go and I posted an answer to cover it.

Comment: `mdls` too? And how about adding `do shell script` in the AppleScript code? But yeah, I just wanted to hint to get OP started.

Comment: @ankii, No `mdls` in the _shell script_ isn't needed here, however `mdfind` does require **Spotlight Indexing** of the target _directory_. By itself this is better suited to a _shell script_ using `launchd` then a `do shell script` _command_ in **AppleScript**. I'll add details for that tomorrow, I'm done for the day.

Comment: You could just create a Smart Folder in the Finder that would automatically list files opened x days ago. Adding a Tag to those files would then be a right-click.

Comment: @benwiggy, That's true, however, the OP clearly states "Automatically tagging files that were last opened more than x days ago" and your solution requires manual tagging, not automatic tagging as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a *file* is tagged in **Finder** it has an *extended attribute* set on it:

`com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags`

**General Information**

The easiest way I've found to apply a *custom* **tag** to a *file* programmatically is to use `xattr` to get the *value* of a *custom* **tag**, not one of the *default* **tags**, and apply it to the *target file(s)* via a *shell script*. For example, I created a new *custom* **tag** named **Review**, giving it the color **yellow**. Its ***hex*** representation is:

```
62706C6973743030A101585265766965770A35080A0000000000000101000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000013
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

To get the *value* of the *custom* **tag**'s `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` *extended attribute*, after having set it normally in **Finder**, the following example *compound command* was use in **Terminal**, e.g.:

```
xattr -px com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags "/path/to/file" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

- <sub>**Note:** When using the above example *compound command* the **prompt** is not returned as normal and is directly after the ***hex** string* instead of being on the next line, so when copying the ***hex** string* make sure **not to copy** any of the **prompt**!</sub>

The output of the `xattr` *command* to see standard output would be, e.g.:

```
$ xattr -l "/path/to/file"
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags:
00000000  62 70 6C 69 73 74 30 30 A1 01 58 52 65 76 69 65  |bplist00..XRevie|
00000010  77 0A 35 08 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00  |w.5.............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 13                                   |.....|
00000035
$
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

However, for this purpose just the ***hex** string* is wanted, hence the use of the `-px` *option* previously, and why *piping* the output to the `tr` *command* to delete *newlines*, `\n`, and *spaces* is necessary.

**Applying Custom Tag**

To apply this *custom* **tag** in **Terminal** to a *file* for testing, use e.g.:

```
xattr -wx  com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags '62706C6973743030A101585265766965770A35080A0000000000000101000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000013' "/path/to/file"
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

- <sub>**Note:** The `xattr` *man page* does show an example of copying the *extended attribute* from one *directory* to another, which can be applied to *files* too, however for a programmatic solution I prefer this method. See `man xargs` in **Terminal** for additional information.</sub>

**Programmatic Usage**

This could be used in a `bash` *script* or in **Automator** using a **Run Shell Script** *action*, however the **Find Finder Items** *action* and **Filter Finder Items** *action* in **Automator** has a *bug* with the **Date last opened** setting.

This leaves using the `find` *command* or the `mdfind` *command*, the latter being better at finding *files* for the **Date Last Opened** as shown in **Finder** in **List** *view* or the **Get Info** *sheet* for a given *file*, which is the `kMDItemLastUsedDate` *attribute* used with the `mdfind` *command* using a properly formed *query*. Note that `mdfind` does require **Spotlight Indexing** of the target *directory*, and is turned on by default.

In **Terminal**, this *compound command* example uses `mdfind` to locate *files* matching the *query* and its result it passed to `xargs` to run `xattr` on the *files* to apply the *custom* **tag**:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin "$HOME/Documents" 'kMDItemLastUsedDate > $time.today(-7) && kMDItemLastUsedDate < $time.today(-6)' | xargs -0 -I % xattr -wx com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags '62706C6973743030A101585265766965770A35080A0000000000000101000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000013' %
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

How this gets wrapped in a *shell script* or in **Automator** using a **Run Shell Script** *action* and scheduled to run at a regular interval really depends on how one intends to schedule it and other criteria surrounding how one intends to take into account its usage and other controls so as not to just run wild, if you will.

I would probably choose to use `launchd` to schedule this as a `bash` *script* and stay away from **Automator**, that is depending on what else one is wanting to be a part of the overall process.

For testing purposes, under **macOS High Sierra**, this is what I did:

**1.** Create a `bash` *script* with the example `mdfind` *compound command* from above.

In **Terminal**:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
touch crtag
open -e crtag
```

The last *command* above should, by default, open **crtag**, for [**C**]ustom[**R**]eview[**Tag**], in **TextEdit**, in which the following lines were added:

```
#!/bin/bash

mdfind -0 -onlyin "$HOME/Documents" 'kMDItemLastUsedDate > $time.today(-7) && kMDItemLastUsedDate < $time.today(-6)' | xargs -0 -I % xattr -wx com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags '62706C6973743030A101585265766965770A35080A0000000000000101000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000013' %
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

Saved the e.g. **crtag** document and closed it.

Back in **Terminal**, made `crtag` executable, e.g.:

```
chmod 0755 crtag
```

<sup>Note: `0755` translates to: `-rwxr-xr-x`</sup>

**2.** Create a **PLIST** *file* for `launchd` to run the e.g. `crtag` *shell script* daily at the desired time.

In **Terminal**:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
touch com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist
open -e com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist
```

The last *command* above should, by default, open **com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist** in **TextEdit**, in which the following lines were added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/path/to/script</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>9</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>00</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

While setting `/path/to/script` to the actual *fully qualified pathname*, e.g. `/Users/me/bin/crtag`, and the *time* as shown in the `<key>Hour</key>`, `<integer>9</integer>` and `<key>Minute</key>`, `<integer>00</integer>` *keys*, which uses **24 Hour** *time*.

Saved the e.g. **com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist** document and closed it.

Back in **Terminal**, loaded the e.g. **com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist** *file* for `launchd` to run the *shell script*, per its settings:

```
launchctl load com.my.DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag.plist
```

Now every day at e.g. **9:00 AM**, the *files* meeting the `mdfind` *query* will have the *custom* **tag** applied to them, which can be viewed in **Finder** from the **Tags** section on the **Sidebar**, or other **Finder** methods involving **Tags**.

---

**Note:** See the manual pages in **Terminal**  for `mdfind`, `launchd`, `launchctl`, `tr`, `xargs` and `xattr`, e.g. `man mdfind`. Also have a look at: [File Metadata Query Expression Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html)

Comment: Excellent answer. +1

Comment: @klanomath, I'll update the answer with appropriate information for **macOS Mojave** and later. Thanks for letting me know as I hadn't had time to test in that environment yet. As far as the name, I had to call it something and that's just what came to mind. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: In Catalina `bash` (or better: the shebanged shell exec in *crtag*) has to be added to **SysPrefs > Priv & Sec > Privacy > Full Disk Access** to allow access to ~/Documents or other protected user folders and tag files there. In user created folders (e.g. ~/Data) the *DateLastOpenedCustomReviewTag* launch agent works flawlessly. I would rename it to *WiederVorlage* (which is a  very important task in German bureaucrazy ~ "for resubmission" in English) though;-)! +1

Comment: A big thank-you for the thorough response and step by step guide.  I applied the custom tag using xattr which was the key and did some batch processing and everything worked as advertised. Appreciate that the solution is applicable beyond the scope of this problem.